# How can I get a total for a previous length of time at a given point in time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm compiling a Year-to-Date list of MID's that have fallen off of our reports (just for context of this question think of a MID as a customer) for a specific portfolio. What this query currently does is show the last period that the MID appeared on our reports before falling off as well as the volume and transactions that MID had in that final month.

What I'm trying to do is get that volume and transaction column to show the volume and transactions that MID had for the 6 months previous to falling off. For example, if the last month the MID appeared is June, I want to see the volume and transactions that MID had from January through June. What's the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Query below:

```
SELECT cur.RESIDUAL_PERIOD AS [Last Residual Period Seen],
       cur.MID,
       cur.DBA AS [Business Name],
       cur.OPEN_DATE AS [Open Date],
       cur.CANCELED_DATE AS [Close Date],
       SUM(cur.VOLUME) AS [Previous 6 Months Volume],
       SUM(cur.TRANSACTIONS) AS [Previous 6 Months Transactions]
FROM BI_DATA_MAP_201906 cur
WHERE RESIDUAL_PERIOD > '2018-12-01'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM BI_DATA_MAP_201906 nxt
                  WHERE nxt.MID = cur.MID
                    AND nxt.RESIDUAL_PERIOD >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(cur.RESIDUAL_PERIOD, 0))
                    AND nxt.RESIDUAL_PERIOD < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(cur.RESIDUAL_PERIOD, 1)))
GROUP BY cur.RESIDUAL_PERIOD,
         cur.MID,
         cur.DBA,
         cur.OPEN_DATE,
         cur.CANCELED_DATE
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] there is little chance anybody can offer much assistance here.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for that link; that's good to know.

Comment: Do you have an audit table?

Comment: @BJones I do not. It's a fairly rudimentary database, and these numbers come from reports that're uploaded each month containing data for the previous month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get each previous months details as a high level figure or all of the transactions for said MID?

If all you need is the Sums for each previous month from the above query then I'd left join / outer apply 6 times the table needed to get said data. Maybe best to create this query as a temp table first.

Sudo SQL below. #temp is your query above as a temp table and I am only joining the first previous month as an example. You would do 5 more joins / outer applys incrementing the dates on the join for the other months. The Date range in the join might need a wee review but the logic is sound.

What is this doing? 
Getting the sums for each mid in #temp and left joining from BI_DATA_MAP_201906 . I guess previous months going back some time will also be on that table. If not, make a table for the left join which goes way back. Sample your final report.

All you need to do is join each previous month on the MID , the last date it was seen and the date range that month is for.  I may not be reading your query right - its been a long day. Hope that helps!

```
SELECT 
main.[Last Residual Period Seen],
main.MID,
main.[Business Name],
main.[Open Date],
main.[Close Date],
main.[Previous 6 Months Volume],
main.[Previous 6 Months Transactions], 
-- this is month minus 1. you would copy the join, update the dates and name it accordingly.
MonthMinus1.Volume,
MonthMinus1.Transaction
FROM #temp as   main
-- 1st previous month
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
SUM(cur.VOLUME) as Volume,
SUM(cur.TRANSACTIONS) as Transaction 
 FROM BI_DATA_MAP_201906 
) as MonthMinus1 
on (MonthMinus1.MID = main.MID) /*join the mid*/
AND /*join date for the month minus 1*/
(
MonthMinus1.RESIDUAL_PERIOD > (EOMONTH ( main.[Last Residual Period Seen], -2 )+1) 
and 
MonthMinus1.RESIDUAL_PERIOD <= EOMONTH ( main.[Last Residual Period Seen], -1 ) 
)
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get high level information. I don't care about the information related to each individual transaction, I just want to know the total number (if that helps).

Comment: Ok cool. I’ll update my answer. Can I ask if you are allowed to put the existing query to a temp table?

Comment: Yes I'm able to no problem.